# Kibana : How to show only limited lines/words around search term, and not full document?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-6

I have documents, having 1000s of lines, indexed in elastic search and  I am trying to search these documents using Kibana. It is working fine. But as Kibana returns full document in search result, user has to scroll a lot to see their search terms in the document.

How can I make Kibana just to return few lines surrounding search term and not the full document?

for example if searchable text in my document is

> It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair. —Charles Dickens, A Tale of Two Cities

So, if I am searching word **belief**, instead of returning full paragraph, I just want to return few words (for large documents, just few lines) before and after it.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use `_source` to retrieve the fields you want from the searched document. Here is an example

I  have this document in `movies` index

```
  {
    "_index" : "movies",
    "_type" : "movie",
    "_id" : "58559",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "id" : "58559",
      "title" : "Dark Knight, The",
      "year" : 2008,
      "genre" : [
        "Action",
        "Crime",
        "Drama",
        "IMAX"
      ]
    }
  }
```

and when I search on this document and I only need to pull the tittle, here is how I do it.

```
GET /movies/_search?pretty
 {
   "query":{
      "match":{
         "year": "2008"
       }
   },
      "_source":[
          "title"
      ]

}
```

I searched on `year` and the resulting document showed only the `title` that I wanted. Here is the response from the above query

```
{
    "_index" : "movies",
    "_type" : "movie",
    "_id" : "58559",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "title" : "Dark Knight, The"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but I think I did not explain my problem properly. I have updated my question with example.

Comment: ok. looking into it to see if there is any `post_filter` or some sort of `sort` that takes the whole string and returns only a few words around the matched term.